# How to save the current user to a variable

Tags: bash

I want 'me' to equal $whoami , but when I try to do it I just print "whoami" as a string instead of the actual value. Would it be possible to use a pipe to connect the variable and the command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
me="$(whoami)"
```

to store command `whoami` output to shell variable `me`

Answer (score 9):

what about:

```
me="$USER"
```

but why should you do this ? It is already an environment variable :-)

```
echo "$USER"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two simple solution, using whoami and USER :

**WHOAMI**

```
me="$(whoami)"
```

result : me=myusername

**USER**

```
me="${USER}"
```

result : me=myusername

but if you are in domain : me=dnsdomain\myusername

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ me=$(whoami)
$ echo "$me"
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this?

```
whoami=$(whoami)
echo $whoami # prints the value of whoami
```